# Meaning of "broken shell of a man"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, idioms, definition

Rachel: So, got any advice? Y'know, as someone who's recently been- dumped?

Ross: Well, you may wanna steer clear of the word 'dumped'. Chances are he's gonna be this, this **broken shell of a man**

Comment: One of the definitions of _shell_ from Oxford Dictionaries:  _an outer form without substance.
"he was a shell of the man he had been previously"_

Comment: Please kindly see our help center rules to know how to ask questions the right way. You need to tell us what research you have done to solve your problem. Have you tried a dictionary? What did you find? Have you tried google? What did you find?

Comment: @AIQ I agree. Looks like Sagar is learning English partly by watching "Friends" (judging by their other questions) and coming up against idiomatic expressions and things said for comedic effect, but even so, a Google search shouldn't be that hard.

Answer (score 1):

The dialog is from [Friends Season 1 Episode 2](https://www.wattpad.com/278976595-friends-season-1-episode-2).  More complete quote here:

> **Rachel** (to Monica): Oh, like I wasn't dreading tomorrow enough, having to give it back to him... 'Hi Barry! Remember me? I'm the girl in the veil who stomped on your heart in front of your entire family!' Oh God and now I'm gonna have to return the ring, without the ring, which makes it so much harder...
>
> ....
>
> **Rachel**: So, got any advice? Y'know, as someone who's recently been- dumped?
>
> **Ross**: Well, you may wanna steer clear of the word 'dumped'. Chances are he's gonna be this, this broken shell of a man, y'know, so you should try not to look too terrific, I know it'll be hard.  Or, y'know, uh, hey!, I'll go down there, and I'll give Barry back his ring, and you can go with Carol and Susan to the OB/GYN...

Ross wrongly predicted that Barry was going to be so devastated after being dumped by Rachel at the altar in front of all his family members at their wedding, so asked Rachel to not looking too good.

"broken shell of a man" thus refers to a man who lost his pride, so looking just physically a man, but without his manliness, thus only a "shell", like a skeleton without the flesh.

Answer (score 1):

The following are all very similar in meaning to "*a broken shell of a man*":

- a man who is very sad
- a depressed man
- a husk of a man
- a sullen man